# How to connect to a secure RabbitMQ cluster through a nginx load balancer

Tags: c#, nginx, ssl, rabbitmq, load-balancing

I have a RabbitMQ cluster running on 3 Linux servers and attempting to securely (via SSL/TLS) connect .net clients via a nginx load balancer.

I am being told this is impossible due to nginx doesn't support secure AMQP and I must use STOMP/web-STOMP, which is not supported by the active RabbitMQ .Net client/nuget package.

Are there any load balancer alternatives (non-nginx?), workarounds (a 'hidden' nginx config setting?), and/or packages that will allow a .Net client to securely connect to a load balanced cluster via AMQP?

Comment: You can have nginx terminate TLS and forward the traffic to localhost 5672 (AMQP)

Comment: @jrhodin If you know _how_ to configure that, would you mind typing it up in an answer?

Comment: @jrhodin Thank you for the reply. Our network admin says that would expose the traffic in plain text, defeating the purpose of making the transaction secure. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @KevinRF Maybe I misunderstood the premise: my comment was with the idea that you run nginx on the same machine as RabbitMQ, so there wouldn't be any additional network where the plain text would be visible.

Comment: @KevinRF Is this a high-security context? Like Banking?

Comment: @jrhodin _"I have a RabbitMQ cluster running on 3 Linux servers"_ could have been a hint :D. Doesn't make much sense to have 3 Loadbalancers - one on each Rabbit-Server, does it?

Comment: BTW: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64536773/982149) doesn't help, does it?

Comment: @Fildor No, not at all.  We got dinged in a security audit because the rabbitmq username+password were being sent across the wire in plain text. That led our admins into wanting *everything* secure.

Comment: @jrhodin "Maybe I misunderstood .." No worries. I appreciate the reply.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the link. Our admin says he has the nginx LB configured exactly as directed in the documentation.  TL;DR, we have another rabbitmq cluster installed on Windows Server behind a LB, and it works fine. Not secure, yet, but I don't know enough about the difference between why the windows version of RabbitMQ works and the linux install doesn't.

Comment: Hmmm, ... now, _that's_ interesting. And there must be a solution ... you cannot possibly be the _only one_ wanting to securely run a linux rabbit mq cluster behind a nginx LB ... amirite?